# Prevent Windows from silently disabling wallpaper slide show

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop, desktop-customization

I generally have my wallpaper set to a slide show pulled from a folder that has around 50 images in it. However, this slide show seems to get stopped whenever I RDP into the system. There is no warning given when this happens, and it does not resume the next time that I log in locally. The only way for me to re-start it is to go back into my wallpaper settings and re-select all the pictures in the folder.

Is there a way to keep Windows from stopping the slide show during an RDP session, or at least to ensure that it will properly re-start it when I log in locally again?

I'm running Windows 7 Ultimate.

Answer (score 2):

Open the Remote Desktop Connection app, click on "Show Options" and go to the "Experince" tab. There, the default option is "Detect connection quality automatically", set that to the manual one, which gives you the largest option of bandwidth - see if that helps. Try Satellite, or high-speed broadband...Hope this helps! It has been known that this is a bug in Windows 7, so I'm not 100% sure this will work.

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered this same behavior on Citrix Receiver. While not a solution, I've found a fairly decent workaround that at least prevents me having to manually reselect each and every wallpaper.

First, get your wallpaper slideshow set up the way you like it. Once you've done so, in the Personalization window, click `Save Theme` and give it a name like "Desktop Slideshow Enabled".

Now when you connect to your RDP, open up the Personalization window and you'll find that the system has switched to "Unsaved Theme" with a static background. Just click your "Slideshow" theme to activate it; you'll most likely immediately see the wallpaper cycle to the next one. There's no OK button to click or anything, so now it's only a 4-click operation to restore your wallpaper slideshow settings, instead of the big pain it was before.